# How to map all possible RGB color combinations to a predefined scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, mapping, rgb

I am trying to map all 16,277,216 possible RGB color combos to a scale of 0 to 100.

Basically, I want red to correspond to 100 and degrade down to orange, yellow, green, blue and eventually black which will have a value of 0.

UPDATE:
This is what I was thinking so far...

```
#Create a list of all values in the scale
import numpy as np
scale = np.linspace(0, 100, num=(256**3))
```

From here it would be great if I could create another list of all possible RGB values (in order). Then I would create a dictionary to basically serve as a look-up table.

There may be a smarter way to do it but this is my current train of thought.

Comment: can you post some code you have done ?

Comment: maybe you want something like https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html ?

Comment: @Dadep I've only created the scale from 0-100 at the appropriate size for all RGB combos, see above.

Comment: @ChrisUnice Problem is that you did not define the order. For instance it is not clear where you want white or grays. My guess is you don't know how to define a sane order (me neither) but that's hardly a question about programming.

Comment: it's a little bit unclear, what is it for ? because if you want use it to plot, you can create a color map, if it's just to scale value from [0 to 16,277,216] to [0 to 100] you should just do `x=x*100.0/ 16277216.0` or  from [0 to 100]  to [0 to 16,277,216]  you should just do `x=x*16277216.0/ 100.0` ... I don't really understand ....

Comment: Your question is contradictory: red, orange, yellow, green, blue and black is just a small subset of all possible rbg colors. So you have to decide: do you want (a) a colormap of red, orange, yellow, green, blue and black or (b) a colormap of all possible rgb colors (where you would also need to define the order of colors in order for this question to be answerable).